# Authenticate my spring boot app using a restful login api

Tags: spring, rest, api, spring-boot, spring-security

I am developing a spring boot app that Authenticate the user against an end point login API, i.e:

We usually checks the username and password saved in DB directly. But this time the credential is in Login end point API that been developed by another programmer.

My Spring boot app that requires a user authentication "login form" against that login api. Before grant access to the application. In other word the username and password comes from an API not saved in DB!  Which that’s login api already developed by others. Any idea? I have not done that before! the login API is:

```
POST: domain/authenticate/user
```

Body is:

```
{    "username" : "user",  
     "password" : "test"
}
```

Response is:

```
{
"customer": {
    "id": 62948,
    "email": "test@test.com.au",
    "givenName": "A",
    "familyName": "OB",
    "user": {
        "id": 63158,
        "version": 1,
        "email": "adamo@test.com.au",
        "password": "113b984921197350abfedb0a30f6e215beeda6c718e36559f48eae946664b405c77bc6bab222fe8d3191f82925921438b6566dda76613aa6cd4416e5d9ae51c8",
        "givenName": "A",
        "familyName": "OB",
     },
    "vehicles": [
        {
            "id": 79369,
            "version": 0,
            "country": "Australia"
            },
            "newState": null,
        }
    ],
    "fundingSources": [
        {
            "@class": "au.com.test.test",
            "id": 54795,
            "version": 0,
        }
    ],
    
    "citySuburb": null,
}
```

}

Comment: The question is fine. Are you going to use the response information while the user session is active?

Comment: Yes correct, because after login I need to use the user response details in my app.

Comment: Any suggestion ? I have not found any of this scenario online !!!

Comment: Unfortunately some people the only thing to do is downgrade others questions. Im not sure why i got -1 i have searched the stack overflow before posting I couldn't find this type of  question !!!

Comment: I think that is not fair from stack overflow. Cause people here want to learn we are not experienced, we learn then we become experienced

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to create a client to consume your rest api for authentication:

```
@Service
public class AuthService {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate authRestTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder().rootUri("http://domain/authenticate").build();
    }

    public Customer authenticate(MultiValueMap<String, String> request) {
        return authRestTemplate().postForObject("/user", request, Customer.class);
    }

    public MultiValueMap<String, String> createRequest(String username, String password) {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> request = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        request.add("username", username);
        request.add("password", password);
        return request;
    }

}
```

Then you have to create a component or a service to consume that client:

```
@Service
public class AuthenticationService implements AuthenticationProvider {

private AuthService authService;

@Autowired
public void setAuthService(AuthService authService) {
    this.authService = authService;
}

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    String username = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

    Customer customer = authService.authenticate(authService.createRequest(username, password));
    if (customer != null) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
//here you need to store your Customer object to use it anywhere while the user is logged in
// take a look on the edit
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, grantedAuthorities);
    }
    throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Invalid credentials.");

}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}

}
```

Finally you need to do the base security configuration using your custom authentication service:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @Autowired
    public void setAuthenticationService(AuthenticationService authenticationService) {
        this.authenticationService = authenticationService;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter webSecurityConfig() {
        return new WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http
                        .csrf()
                        .disable()
                        .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .and()
                        .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                        .and()
                        .logout()
                        .permitAll();
            }

            @Override
            protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
                builder.authenticationProvider(authenticationService);
            }

        };

        }
}
```

You need to create DTO of your login api response in `Customer` object and think about how to store the information into the list of `GrantedAuthority`

There are many others options you can use but this is the easies for me.

**Edit: *Here is just an idea how to implement the GrantedAuthority for your authentication api:***

First you need an object that implements the interface and stores the whole json:

```
public class CustomerGrantedAuthority implements org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority {

    private String customerJson;

    public CustomerGrantedAuthority(String customerJson){
        this.customerJson = customerJson;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return customerJson;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        CustomerGrantedAuthority that = (CustomerGrantedAuthority) o;
        return java.util.Objects.equals(customerJson, that.customerJson);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return java.util.Objects.hash(customerJson);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.customerJson;
    }

}
```

Better solution is to make an object and store it as an object not as a string but just for the example it is a string.

Then you need to change the `AuthenticationService` in your code where you access the authentication api:

```
String customer = new RestTemplate().postForObject("http://domain/authenticate/user", createRequest(username, password), String.class);
    if (customer != null) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
    grantedAuthorities.add(new CustomerGrantedAuthority(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(customer)));
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, grantedAuthorities);
    }
    throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Invalid credentials.");

public MultiValueMap<String, String> createRequest(String username, String password) {
            MultiValueMap<String, String> request = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            request.add("username", username);
            request.add("password", password);
            return request;
        }
```

It depends where and how you want to access your user information in your app but just to see if it works you can make a test with simple RestController, that should be visible when the user is logged in:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/auth")
    public ResponseEntity getAuth() {
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
        CustomerGrantedAuthority customer = (CustomerGrantedAuthority) authorities.stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
        return customer != null ? ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).body(customer.getAuthority()) : ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }

}
```

Sorry for the long post and I apologize if there are spelling mistakes. As I said this is just my opinion and there are a lot of others solutions.

Comment: The answer looks promising and i couldn't get that from anywhere in the web thanks heaps. 
I'm going to implement it and let you know! 
The only part didn't get is : "You need to create DTO of your login api response in Customer object and think about how to store the information into the list of GrantedAuthority"  ?

Comment: You can use a [tool](https://codebeautify.org/json-to-java-converter) to create the Customer object that you can use to serialize your respone from the authentication api.

Comment: Or store the whole json into the [GrantedAuthority](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/GrantedAuthority.html)

Comment: Lovely I will follow what u just told me. Thanks Nikolay Hristov :)

Comment: I have implemented what u guided me, it works with no errors. the only thing is the login page returns invalid username/password. Im debugging to find out why, but if you have anything in mind let me know please. I appreciate that

Comment: Look if the RestTemplate returns what you expect. If it is ok check the implementation of the AuthenticationProvider. If it is ok too probably the problem comes from WebMvcConfiguration. Good luck.

Comment: I have debugged the implementation of AuthenticationProvider as u suggested and found out that I'm having a null customer !

Comment: Hi I have managed how to fix the login, was a long journey for me ! The only think left is I need to get the response from Customer so I can use it in my app, this stage I have null Customer. Any hints ? thanks

Comment: It depends where and how you want to access your user information. Take a look on the edit.

Comment: Thanks for your help, am asking a lot on this scenario cause i have not faced it before, anyways i implement it, but still having a null customer. See my Github: https://github.com/App-Teck/PermitsUI.git

Comment: I tried to make a new branch but I couldn't. So I [forked into my repository](https://github.com/nikixp/PermitsUI). The problem was into your Customer pojo.

Comment: The only thing left, is pulling the data from the json response "after login". Now we can print on the console for testing "in AuthenticationService.java", but I also want to render some data to the jsp file.

Comment: In jsp pages you can with javascript calling /auth with ajax. You cat also inject anywhere in your backend the AuthController.

Comment: Thanks very much my application is completed. I learned new skills from you, hope all the programmers sharing their skills and knowledge with others to tach the world...